# CakePHP database file specification

Tags: database, cakephp, configuration

I'm trying to find something about CakePHP configuration, and I'm not having any luck googling and looking around.
I want to make a CakePHP app use "database.local.php" instead of "database.php", but I can't find the line in the app/Config files where the database file is defined as "database.php".
Does anyone know where it is defined so I can change it?

Thanks for your help ahead of time!

Comment: Why do you want to use a different name?

Answer (score 1):

If i get it right, you want to have a local database... for development purpose?

If you want to switch the database due to your server-name, you can try to use:
http://www.edwardawebb.com/web-development/cakephp/automatically-choose-database-connections-cakephp

Comment: Be careful when using this approach, because 'servername' and 'hostname' may not be set when running (Cake)PHP from the command-line (e.g. CakeShell or cron-jobs)

Comment: You could also create a Flag in a conf file where you check which one to use... how it is decided which one to use can be accomplished in multible ways :)

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to warn the OP for this, in case he needed to use the CommandLine. There are various ways to achieve this, adding an `include('database.something.php');` to `database.php` may be something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer for you, but I wouldn't change it.

If you're using different files for different environments (dev, staging, production etc) you could use your naming convention, but have your deploy process rename the relevant file to whatever CakePHP's expecting. That is, have:

```
database.local.php
database.uat.php
database.live.php
```

or whatever, and just rename to database.php when deploying your code to one of those environments.